# Autocomplete of a citation based on the Title not the Key in TeXstudio with Bibtex

Tags: bibtex, texstudio, auto-completion

I am Using BibTex and \cite in TeXstudio, is it possible to get the filtered pop up suggestion menu based on the title? I'm seeing \cite generates the popup menu and suggests and filters citations as I type but it is based on the citation key not the title.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. TeXstudio does only parse the bibtex key. It does not analyze the content of bibtex entries.

Comment: Thank you so much, i think it would be a good option to have

Comment: There's an open feature request for this (https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/623/). However we would need a decent BibTeX parser, which we do not have time to write ourselves. If you know a good Qt library for BibTeX parsing, let us know.